Ethernet on a USB-C hub not working on startup, but works if plugged in after boot
I have a USB-C hub with an Ethernet port. My laptop is a Dell XPS9560.
It works perfectly if I plug in the device after booting the system. But if I plug it in and then boot the system, other USB devices connected to the USB-C hub work, but the Ethernet port is recognized but not working.
I compared the output of lsusb, lspci and lsmod | grep net, and they are the same.
ip addr show eth0 shows that the eth0 device has not been created. If I unplug the hub and then plug it in, the eth0 device is created.
I am using the 6.6.58 Linux kernel.
What am I missing here?
dmesg
 kernel: usb 4-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0b95, idProduct=1790, bcdDevice= 2.00
 kernel: usb 4-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
 kernel: usb 4-1.1: Product: AX88179A
 kernel: usb 4-1.1: Manufacturer: ASIX
 kernel: usb 4-1.1: SerialNumber: 00000000001BDD
 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: VGA decodes changed: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
 kernel: Loading firmware: i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin


Do you have anything interesting in dmesg at around the point where the USB device gets detected? Usually there'll be some messages from the USB Ethernet driver afterward.

I've added dmesg. It looks like after the kernel discovered the device, it moved on without initializing the ethernet.

Which Linux distribution are you using? Do you have any unusual setup like separate / and /usr partitions, or a system without udev? Does modprobe ax88179_178a initialize the device?

It looks like like during boot the hub is initialized in the initramfs, but it doesn't include the Ethernet driver (module, firmware or both); whereas, when initialization takes place in main system, the module and firmware are already available and it all works well.

Watch your system boot and discover/initialize your hardware with sudo journalctl  -b 0. Do sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes" within 4 minutes of plugging in the adapter. Compare.
